# Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0'

Tags: linux, phpstorm, root

I want to open phpStorm with this code :

```
sudo phpstorm
```

because i want to access to root mode. And I've got this error message in terminal :

```
> No protocol specified
> Start Failed: Failed to initialize graphics environment

> java.awt.AWTError: Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.
at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.initDisplay(Native Method)
at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.access$200(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:65)
at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment$1.run(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:115)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.<clinit>(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:74)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.createGE(GraphicsEnvironment.java:103)
at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(GraphicsEnvironment.java:82)
at sun.awt.X11.XToolkit.<clinit>(XToolkit.java:128)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:860)
at java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:855)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(Toolkit.java:854)
at java.awt.Toolkit.getEventQueue(Toolkit.java:1734)
at java.awt.EventQueue.isDispatchThread(EventQueue.java:1049)
at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread(SwingUtilities.java:1361)
at javax.swing.text.StyleContext.reclaim(StyleContext.java:454)
at javax.swing.text.StyleContext.addAttribute(StyleContext.java:311)
at javax.swing.text.html.StyleSheet.addAttribute(StyleSheet.java:578)
at javax.swing.text.StyleContext$NamedStyle.addAttribute(StyleContext.java:1501)
at javax.swing.text.StyleContext$NamedStyle.setName(StyleContext.java:1312)
at javax.swing.text.StyleContext$NamedStyle.<init>(StyleContext.java:1259)
at javax.swing.text.StyleContext.addStyle(StyleContext.java:107)
at javax.swing.text.StyleContext.<init>(StyleContext.java:87)
at javax.swing.text.html.StyleSheet.<init>(StyleSheet.java:166)
at javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit.getStyleSheet(HTMLEditorKit.java:391)
at com.intellij.util.ui.UIUtil.<clinit>(UIUtil.java:103)
at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager.start(PluginManager.java:78)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.ide.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:39)
at com.intellij.idea.Main.main(Main.java:78)
```

I can run phpstorm with usermode :

```
phpstorm
```

What should i do ?

Comment: …why are you trying to run an IDE as root? That's all kinds of dangerous.

Comment: @duskwuff because i want to add artisan command to phpstorm, which editor do you suggest to programming with laravel/php ?

Comment: Any [source code editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code_editor) will do (I like [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) but you can use something else). However, you usually should not edit the source code of a program as root (but you need to have some *installation* procedure)

Comment: @user22602 What do you mean by "add artisan command to phpstorm"? Are you trying to modify the IDE?

Comment: looks like you have only "headless" java on your desktop. Please try to reinstall a full version. Similar issues: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-29526, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-17310, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-24816

Comment: @duskwuff thank you all, i found solution, you were right, i shouldn't run IDE as root mode , i reinstalled php, ide and all other extensions and finally get result.